# Pentaho91: Copy datagrid rows to two merge joins. Is this a bug?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon

I used copy-rows for two data grids to test different joins.

Only one join shows preview other results in empty rows. If I preview one at a time, the join results show up, but not when previewed together.

I expect both joins shows-up rows in preview [as i'm using copy-rows option]

Is this a bug?

[image]

Comment: There might have something in your join condition. Can you please share your transformation?

Answer (score 0):

There might have something in your join condition/ Copy row step. Please look into your transformation again.
I have tested your described process. But I found both preview are working as expected.
You can see my sample transformation from [HERE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1h3BniMHSr4Jyy5EHvecmGImjhSL4uuPd/view?usp=sharing). I also use PDI 9.1

[image]